# Double authorization in Postman

Tags: rest, magento, postman, basic-authentication

I have basic auth on the website, how can I include two authorization methods in the header, Bearer and token?
Is it at all possible if so how, because if I give it like this:

[image]

This is when one overwrites the other and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple Authorizations using a comma

```
Authorization: Basic X,Bearer Y
```

X is the base64 encoded `username:password`. Basic must come before the Bearer.

If you want to set it in the parent you may consider using pre-request script:

```
const X = btoa('user:pass');
const Y = 'BEARER TOKEN';
pm.request.headers.add({
    key: 'Authorization',
    value: `Basic ${X},Bearer ${Y}`,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Postman to test the API, it already supports adding authorization when calling the API
Access:
In the Authorization section select Bearer Token and enter your token
Note: You cannot add authorization to headers

Comment: I have same issue, I've got dev/uat site which has basic Auth, the API is a bearer token, any ideas how to first use basic to access the site and then bearer for the api's ?